# Running Selenium/Thucydides JUnit test in alphabetical order using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, junit4, thucydides

I have a Selenium/Thucydides project that runs test cases using JUnit.
In Eclipse when running using JUnit I can use `@FixMethodOrder` to run tests in alphabetical order. This works fine, but when I then run the test in Maven using `mvn verify` the tests are run randomly.

I have seen that you can set `<runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>` in the pom.xml but it doesn't seem to work either.

Are there anyway to run the tests alphabetically when using Maven? (I know they shouldn't be dependent on each other but some are at this point in time, so need this option till I can make them independent)

POM.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.team.app</groupId>
<artifactId>Testing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Selenium Testing</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <thucydides.version>0.9.127</thucydides.version>
    <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.thucydides</groupId>
        <artifactId>thucydides-core</artifactId>
        <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.thucydides</groupId>
        <artifactId>thucydides-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
              <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder> 
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
              <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder> 
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/When*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                </systemPropertyVariables>                                      
                <!-- <parallel>parallel</parallel> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>                
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.thucydides.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-thucydides-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>thucydides-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>maven2</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <missing>${basedir}</missing>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.thucydides.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-thucydides-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>maven3</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${basedir}</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0-beta-3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>net.thucydides.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-thucydides-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<description>Project that perform automated user test on Bosted using Selenium and Thucydides</description>
```

JUnit:

```
  @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
  @Story(Application.PlanModernusConfiguration.ConfigureFieldDefinitions.class)
  @RunWith(ThucydidesRunner.class)
```

And using `@Test` methods that are in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

`<runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>` works as expected for me.

I'm also running Thucydides with failsafe 2.15, parallel off, etc... Configuration is almost identical only the targeted java version is 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Or at least I solved it by downgrading to `Maven 2.2.1`.
It seems `Maven 3.0.x` doesn't abide by the `runOrder` parameter for some reason.
But don't need v3 specifically, so downgrading is fine for me.
Still strange though.